# Unable to simulate curl in postman

Tags: json, api, curl, request, postman

I have a curl request as below:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '[]' http://localhost:3000/v1/api/current.json
```

When I hit the above request in command prompt I get status 200 which is ok. I'm trying to simulate this request using Postman but not sure how to handle it, specifically `-d '[]'`.

`-d` should be data param which I expect a key-value pair but from above I don't see any key involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-d` means it is the request body data

Choose the `PUT` method, then in the `Body` tab, choose `raw` with `application/json`

And fill the `[]` into the text editor area.